# Going beyond the array in Android programming

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

I'm writing a game on Android platform. I have array of buttons and when I click in one of them, it will show up "X" on it and neighbouring buttons like this:

```
  X
X X X
  X
```

But when I click one of the border buttons application is stopping.

This is my method responsible for setting text on buttons (if you need more code, please tell me):

```
private void changeState(int locationVer, int locationHor){
    String buttonText = BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].getText().toString();
    String rightButtonText = BoardButtons[locationVer+1][locationHor].getText().toString();
    String leftButtonText = BoardButtons[locationVer-1][locationHor].getText().toString();
    String lowerButtonText = BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor+1].getText().toString();
    String upperButtonText = BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor-1].getText().toString();
    if(locationVer == 0) {
        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));

            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }


        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }
    }

    else if(locationVer == 6) {
        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));

            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }


        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }
    }

    else if(locationHor == 0) {
        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));

            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }

        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }
    }

    else if(locationHor == 6) {
        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));

            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }

        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }
    }

    else {
        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));

            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }


        if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)) {
            BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (rightButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer + 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (leftButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer - 1][locationHor].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (lowerButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor + 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));

            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE)));
            if (upperButtonText == String.valueOf(Game.EMPTY_SPACE))
                BoardButtons[locationVer][locationHor - 1].setText((String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)));
        }
    }
}
```

This is what logcat shows:

```
06-06 17:13:56.727    2232-2232/pl.edu.uksw.fieldsgame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pl.edu.uksw.fieldsgame, PID: 2232
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
        at pl.edu.uksw.fieldsgame.MainActivity.changeState(MainActivity.java:149)
        at pl.edu.uksw.fieldsgame.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:13)
        at pl.edu.uksw.fieldsgame.MainActivity$ButtonClick.onClick(MainActivity.java:137)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: It would be useful to know what line it is crashing on. Include the complete stack trace when you mention things like the `"application is stopping"`.

Comment: also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java (probably unrelated to your question, but its an obvious problem that jumps out).

Comment: No, it's not because compare strings. I thing lines like "if(locationVer == 0)" doesn't working. I will edit my question and show logcat

Comment: The error should give you a hint ;) The indices of an array in Java run from 0 to length-1, so array[length] is actually out of bounds by 1. It is likely that you are passing a value of `6` as one of the parameters of your function - the first thing you do is `locationVer+1` which would cause the exception. Checking the bounds of locationVer and locationHor upfront might go a long way to fix things.

Comment: Also, please research the difference between `==` and `equals`. I realize its not the source of your current problem, but what you have coded there is just wrong (really asking for trouble).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you're trying to read an index that isn't in the array, in this case you have a length 7 array (indices 0 through 6) but you're asking for position 7, which doesn't exist.

I don't have enough data to align line numbers with your code, but I'm guessing this is coming from this line:

```
String rightButtonText = BoardButtons[locationVer+1][locationHor].getText().toString();
```

You don't check to ensure that `locationVer+1` is a valid array index before trying to read it out of the array.  It looks like your following code will handle `rightButtonText` being `null`, so this should work (repeat for each array read, changing the condition as appropriate for the array index that's being incremented/decremented):

```
String rightButtonText = null;
if (locationVer + 1 < BoardButtons.length) {
    rightButtonText = BoardButtons[locationVer+1][locationHor].getText().toString();
}
```

### Edit:

The next problem you'll have is using `==` vs `.equals()` for comparing strings.  In java the `==` operator used on objects (not primitives) compares references, not values ([see here including answers for more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)).

When you call `if (buttonText == String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER))` you're asking java if `buttonText` is the same string (as in "is the same reference", not "has the same value") as `String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)`.  This will return `false` every time because `String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER)` is creating a new string.  To actually do the comparison you thought you were getting, swap this around to:

```
if (String.valueOf(Game.PLAYER).equals(buttonText))
```

Comment: Ok, it's almost correctly. I can click border buttons but when I'm clicking any button it only sets "X" on middle (clicked), lower and right button. How to fix this?

Comment: Now you're finally hitting the problem with using `==` vs `.equals().  I'll edit this into my answer for the sake of formatting.

Comment: Noooo, it didn't solve this new problem. It sets only 3 "X" again.

Comment: Ok, I finally found the mistake! I had if (locationHor - 1 >= BoardButtons.length) instead of if (locationHor - 1 >= 0)...